# Google Place Detail geometry return lat lng 0

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using google autocomplete to search the place, use selecting a place to get place search detail, but somewhere returning geometry like this

```
 {
data: {
    result: {
           address_components: null,
           adr_address: null,
           formatted_address: "ถนน เยาวราช แขวง สัมพันธวงศ์ เขต สัมพันธวงศ์ กรุงเทพมหานคร ประเทศไทย",
           formatted_phone_number: null,
           icon: null,
           id: "ba0c3670c243f77b96973ab9b758435e464a235c",
           international_phone_number: null,
           name: "ถนน เยาวราช",
           place_id: "Er4B4LiW4LiZ4LiZIOC5gOC4ouC4suC4p-C4o-C4suC4iiDguYHguILguKfguIcg4Liq4Lix4Lih4Lie4Lix4LiZ4LiY4Lin4LiH4Lio4LmMIOC5gOC4guC4lSDguKrguLHguKHguJ7guLHguJnguJjguKfguIfguKjguYwg4LiB4Lij4Li44LiH4LmA4LiX4Lie4Lih4Lir4Liy4LiZ4LiE4LijIOC4m-C4o-C4sOC5gOC4l-C4qOC5hOC4l-C4oiJIKkYKFAoSCfeTYfchmeIwEQI33BtriGRYEhQKEgmXcn7yIZniMBHgiuJdsgABBBoYCgoNShIwCBWteOc7EgoNiFcxCBVLIuk7",
           url: null,
           geometry: {
                 location: {
                     lat: 0,
                     lng: 0
                 },
           viewport: {
                  northeast: {
                            lat: 0.00134898029150203,
                            lng: 0.00134898029150203
                  },
                  southwest: {
                             lat: -0.00134898029150203,
                             lng: -0.00134898029150203
                   }
             }
          }
        },
       status: "OK"
   }}
```

I don't know why returning like this, for another place working fine